# How to find Cassandra active clients?

Tags: cassandra

I am working with Cassandra 3.5.0. Right now I am seeing something rather strange: after I shut down all the client sessions, some tables are still growing and shrinking.

My first reaction was that this must be due to some lingering client task in the background. I tried my very best but couldn't find any. Because this is not a DataStax Enterprise version, I am not able to find an audit log to show active client connections. Is there still a way to find that out?

Answer (score 0):

How did you observe the "growing and shrinking" of these tables?

If your observation is based on the SSTables on the filesystem, or used table space shown in a tool like OpsCenter, probably what you see is the effect of compaction.  You can check on various activities (streams, network exchanges, compactions) using nodetool.
Another possibility is related to the data moving from Memtables to SSTables, all determined by your server setup in combination with the volume of data created.

Also, I suggest looking at the Cassandra logs on the nodes to find more about the on-going activity.

Comment: I caught the changes by constantly running CQL count(*) statement "select count(*) from ...". It went up and down then down and up. I looked and looked but didn't find any active client program (this is a test env that only I have access to). You are probably onto something about streaming - the system.log keeps growing with "repair ..." messages.